# Rails 3.0 undefined local variable when rendering a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml, partial-views

I'm working with a Rails 3.0.20 app and I'm trying to pass a local variable through a partial and it's displaying 'undefined local variable' I've had a look at the other posts on this issue and couldn't fix it.

Here is my call to render the parital

```
    = f.fields_for :current_positions do |builder|
        = render :partial => 'current_position_fields', :locals => {:f => builder, :foo => 'hi'}
```

Here is my partial

```
%tr.pos_start
    %td
        = foo
        = f.hidden_field :id, class: "pos_id"
        = f.label :name, "Position Name"
    %td= f.text_field :name
%tr.pos_loc
    %td= f.label :location, "Position Location"
    %td= f.text_field :location
%tr.pos_end
    %td= f.label :year, "Position Year"
    %td= f.text_field :year
    %td.fields
        = link_to_remove_fields "DEL", f
```

The error message is

```
undefined local variable or method `foo' for #<#<Class:0x00000008d4a050>:0x00000008d3c590>
```

If I take the `= foo` out of the code everything else works.

Comment: What is your exact use case, instead of `foo` pointing to a string? It is currently pointing to a string, so may be `="#{foo}"`?

Comment: I'm trying to make a unique reference for the hidden_field :id so that I can access it through some jquery below to overcome a bug with users hitting the back button in their browser. So instead of 'foo' I will end up passing a counter/index which I will update in the loop where I'm rendering the partial and attach that to the class name for the hidden_field :id and in my script call below. At the moment I'm wondering why I cannot pass a simple string to a partial.

Comment: Your syntax for `render` is completely correct, afaik. Just gave it a shot on my local dev, working just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found my error, I was calling the partial in an application helper as well and not passing on the appropriate local variables.

I found this when I could copy the partial to another name and call that with a variable and it worked.

Comment: I had the same problem and your solution solved it! Thanks!
In my case I had a partial that also uses the render, and I did not change that render when I changed the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 =render 'current_position_fields', :f => builder, :foo => 'hi'
```

Comment: If the one being used by map7 is not working, this won't work either. `render` checks if first argument is a `String` or an `Hash`; if an hash, it interprets it with key/values for partial, locals, collection etc, if first argument is string, it forms the hash itself, by treating first argument as partial name and rest as locals.